# input box taking numeric value in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Using this code, user won't enter numeric value. In Google Chrome, input box is not taking numeric value but in Firefox it takes. I'm not getting, why it is happening. Any help appreciated.

```
<input type="text" name="station_name" id="station_name" onKeyPress="return noNumbers(this)" maxlength="45" />
```

this is my javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function noNumbers(evt)
            {
                var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
                if((charCode>=65 && charCode<=90)||(charCode>=97 && charCode<=122)||(charCode==32))
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, in Firefox, the event is passed as a parameter to the event handler. event property of the window object is IE only.

```
function enterHere(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 13)
        find();
}
```

Comment: `<input type="text" name="station_name" id="station_name" onKeyPress="return noNumbers(event)" maxlength="45" />` need to be change. !!

Answer (score 1):

you are passing `this` in the following line, pass `event`

```
<input type="text" name="station_name" id="station_name" onKeyPress="return noNumbers(event)" maxlength="45" />
```

**EDIT**
ok try the follwoing function and the input tag as above:

```
function noNumbers(evt)
            {
                var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
                if((charCode>=65 && charCode<=90)||(charCode>=97 && charCode<=122)||(charCode==32)||||(charCode==8))
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
```